# ¿Por qué el siguiente código devuelve NaN en consola?

Tags: javascript

Antes que nada, gracias por leer. Soy nuevo en esto de programar y estoy aprendiendo con Javascript. Estoy intentando crear una función que multiplique el primer elemento de un array con el último. Quiero que cuando sea llamada reciba como argumento un array y haga la operación matemática. El array que quiero probar se llama "numeros".

```
let numeros = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 12]; 

function multiplicar(listado) {
  let Ind1 = listado[0];
  let IndF = listado[listado.lenght -1];
  let final = Ind1 * IndF;
  return final;
}
```

Comment: En la asignación de `IndF` tienes `lenght`, pero es `length` la `h` y la `t`están al revés. Así que no encuentra esa propiedad, por lo que `IndF` tiene un valor de `undefined` y estará haciendo `Ind1 * undefined = NaN`. Pon: `let IndF = listado[listado.length -1];`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, realmente era algo muy básico. :) No sé si le sirve a alguien una consulta tan elemental...

Comment: El aprendizaje interesante acá es cómo podrías hacerle debug al código para que las cosas elementales las encuentres tú mismo. ;)

Comment: Es verdad, tienes razón. No es la primera vez que me sucede que paso por alto un error así. Y a pesar de que uso la consola para buscar la línea donde está el problema, con todo y ello a veces no los encuentro. ¿Sabes si existe algún manual o procedimiento estandarizado para "debuguear" el código?

Comment: Aquí tienes la respuesta a lo que buscas: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/

Comment: Excelente, te agradezco mucho.